# _TABLE_SUFFIX string comparisonwith integer

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery tutorial, there is an example mentioned:
There are few tables called gsod1991,gsod1992,gsod1993....gsod2018 under noaa_gsod dataset.
We write a query using _table_suffix filter

```
SELECT *  from `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >'2015'
```

In there gsod2018 is a string and four digits after gsod is used as _TABLE_SUFFIX to do the comparison.
But why any year after 2015 is used a string comparison?
When we want to get year after 2015 table, isn't that a numeric comparison not string comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we want to get year after 2015 table, isn't that a numeric comparison not string comparison?

It doesn't make a difference whether you compare years as strings or as numbers, unless you're comparing years prior to the year 1000 or after the year 9999, since then the years have different numbers of digits. As an example:

```
SELECT
  year,
  year > 2015 AS number_is_greater,
  CAST(year AS STRING) > '2015' AS string_is_greater
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2010, 2020)) AS year;

+------+-------------------+-------------------+
| year | number_is_greater | string_is_greater |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 2010 |             false |             false |
| 2011 |             false |             false |
| 2012 |             false |             false |
| 2013 |             false |             false |
| 2014 |             false |             false |
| 2015 |             false |             false |
| 2016 |              true |              true |
| 2017 |              true |              true |
| 2018 |              true |              true |
| 2019 |              true |              true |
| 2020 |              true |              true |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
```